# codeigniter oc_ prefex database problem in server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, error-handling

i have created a website in codeignter, the website is working fine my local, i uploaded it to my server, then its showing the following error:

```html
Table 'kirana_btp_new.oc_ci_sessions' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`oc_ci_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` = '20e9bf3d13c5fbcad7582f354abaf8e3' AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'

Filename: libraries/Session.php
```

coz my table names doesn't start with _oc, i don't know where this oc is coming from, below is a few code from the session.php where the error is showing.

```html
if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE)
   {
    $this->CI->db->where('user_agent', $session['user_agent']);
   }

   $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);

   // No result?  Kill it!
   if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
   {
    $this->sess_destroy();
    return FALSE;
   }
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong here? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please check your config database file 
you can add there prefix for db prefix

```
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
```

you can check it from application\config\database.php